# Jquery bootstrap unexpected output, except in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My html which uses Bootstrap 4 and jquery 3.2.1, is generated by another script dynamically, and consists of several elements, whose basic unit looks like this:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 95%;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert"><h4>Question 24 of 2947</h4></div></h5>
    <h5 class="card-header"><p>A 72-year-old lady was treated non-operatively following a closed fracture of the radial shaft. Which of the following late complications would you least likely expect to see?Select one answer only</p></h5>
    <p class="card-text"></p><ul><li>(A) Algodystrophy</li><li>(B) Infection</li><li>(C) Non-union</li><li>(D) Tendon rupture</li><li>(E) Volkmann’s ischaemic contracture</li></ul><p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary columbrium" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#yyGOkFXx" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Answer
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="ExpandAllBtnyyGOkFXx">Expand All</button>
<script>
  $( "button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).bind('click', function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
    if ($( ".collapse" ).first().hasClass( "show" )) {
      $( "button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html('Collapse All');
    } else {
      $( "button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html('Expand All');
    }
  });
</script>
<div class="collapse show" id="yyGOkFXx" style="">
<div class="card" style="width: 95%;">
<div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text">                
        </p><h2>Explanation                    
        </h2>
        <div id="ctl00">
            <p><strong>My text</strong></p>
        </div><p></p>
</div>
</div></div>
```

The enclosed javascript is supposed to expand the collapsable bootstrap elements, and also change the name of the button text once a click happens.
Though the code works when run in the console, it does not change the name of the button when the button is clicked, though the elements expand and collapse as expected. What can I be missing?

```js
    $( "button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).bind('click', function() {
      $('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
      if ($( ".collapse" ).first().hasClass( "show" )) {
        $( "button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html('Collapse All');
      } else {
        $( "button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html('Expand All');
      }
    });
```

```html
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>Collection 2018</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
   <div class="card" style="width: 95%;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert"><h4>Question 24 of 2947</h4></div></h5>
        <h5 class="card-header"><p>A 72-year-old lady was treated non-operatively following a closed fracture of the radial shaft. Which of the following late complications would you least likely expect to see?Select one answer only</p></h5>
        <p class="card-text"></p><ul><li>(A) Algodystrophy</li><li>(B) Infection</li><li>(C) Non-union</li><li>(D) Tendon rupture</li><li>(E) Volkmann’s ischaemic contracture</li></ul><p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary columbrium" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#yyGOkFXx" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Answer
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="ExpandAllBtnyyGOkFXx">Expand All</button>
    <div class="collapse show" id="yyGOkFXx" style="">
    <div class="card" style="width: 95%;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">                
            </p><h2>Explanation                    
            </h2>
            <div id="ctl00">
                <p><strong>My text</strong></p>
            </div><p></p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rupvont/

To be clear, my working example does expand and collapse elements fine. ***I'm unable to change the innerhtml of matching elements within displayed html, but able to do so in the console window.*** There are no delayed loading elements, as is evident from the code snippet/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that all Bootstrap 4 methods are asynchronous, so when you call `.collapse()`, it just starts the transition, but immediately returns to the rest of your script. This phenomenon is described under the [Methods](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#methods) section of the Collapse component.

If you `console.log` the value of `$('.collapse').first().hasClass('show')` within your script, you will see that it is always equals to `false`. The collapsible element does not receive the `.show` class immediately when it is about to be shown, but loses it immediately when it is about to be hidden.

A solution to this problem is to use the [Events](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) that a Collapse component emits when toggled. Below you will find a snippet that does that.

```js
// jQuery `.bind()` has been deprecated, use `.on()` instead
$("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']").on('click', function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
    
    // $('.collapse').first().hasClass('show') is always false here
    console.log($('.collapse').first().hasClass('show'));
});

$('.collapse').first().on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']").html('Collapse All');
});

$('.collapse').first().on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']").html('Expand All');
});
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 95%;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert"><h4>Question 24 of 2947</h4></div></h5>
        <h5 class="card-header"><p>A 72-year-old lady was treated non-operatively following a closed fracture of the radial shaft. Which of the following late complications would you least likely expect to see?Select one answer only</p></h5>
        <p class="card-text"></p><ul><li>(A) Algodystrophy</li><li>(B) Infection</li><li>(C) Non-union</li><li>(D) Tendon rupture</li><li>(E) Volkmann’s ischaemic contracture</li></ul><p></p>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary columbrium" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#yyGOkFXx" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">Answer</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="ExpandAllBtnyyGOkFXx">Expand All</button>

<div class="collapse" id="yyGOkFXx" style="">
    <div class="card" style="width: 95%;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Explanation</h2>
            <div id="ctl00">
                <p><strong>My text</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Note: As of jQuery 3.0, the [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method has been deprecated, and you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, due to the asynchronicity of Bootstraps collapse this did not work. In the interest of actually showing a differnet answer to dferencs i have changed mine into a workaround that does not require as many event listeners:

```
$("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']").on("click", function() {
    $(".collapse").collapse("toggle");
    if (($("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html() === "Collapse All") && !$(".collapse").first().hasClass("show")) {
        $("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html("Expand All");
    } else {
        $("button[id^='ExpandAllBtn']" ).html("Collapse All");
    }
});
```

Comment: That still doesnt do anything. Can you fix it in the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, i don't have a lot of time right now. If you still haven't found a solution when i get back i will have a shot at it.

Comment: Btw, in the example I posted, the elements expand and collapse fine. I'm only unable to change the inner html.